# vmware/Linux. Deleting and creating larger partition, it starts later on disk

Tags: linux, partition

I want to make a linux root disk larger under vmware.
I have already epanded the "physical" disk in vmware, fdisk can see the free space.

The partition is ext4.

I have deleted unused swap partitions, so the free space is afterwards the root partition.

I wanted to do it like this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/24027/how-can-i-resize-an-ext-root-partition-at-runtime
Delete partition and recreate it larger, starting at the same position.
But my old partition starts at 63, and the new partion starts at 2048. I have** not** saved the new partion.

**EDIT: Disk expanded from 8 to 20GB,** does this affect where first partition starts?

```
~# fdisk /dev/sda

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.29.2).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sda: 20 GiB, 21474836480 bytes, 41943040 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000a5f05

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       63 15952544 15952482  7.6G 83 Linux

Command (m for help): d
Selected partition 1
Partition 1 has been deleted.

Command (m for help): n
Partition type
   p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)
   e   extended (container for logical partitions)
Select (default p):

Using default response p.
Partition number (1-4, default 1):
First sector (2048-41943039, default 2048):
Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-41943039, default 41943039):

Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux' and of size 20 GiB.

Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sda: 20 GiB, 21474836480 bytes, 41943040 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000a5f05

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sda1        2048 41943039 41940992  20G 83 Linux

Command (m for help): q
```

Why can I not make the new partition start at the same place as the old?
Other options? create a larger disk, dd everything over, and mount new root disk instead of the old?

Comment: I managed to resize using `parted resize part

Comment: Usually you use [GParted](https://gparted.org/) to do it visually. Many people find it is much easier than the command line tools. Just download the ISO and boot to the ISO in your VM. The hard disks will be available for modification.

Answer (score 3):

Your original partition was probably created using an old version of `fdisk` or another partitioning tool that similarly defaulted to creating DOS-compatible partitions.

Your new `fdisk` uses the current recommended partition alignment: by starting the disk's first partition at sector 2048 it will be exactly 1 MiB from the start of the disk. That helps in aligning the partition's data with the structures of the underlying storage system, whether that structure might be:

- 4k blocks on modern multi-terabyte HDDs
- erase blocks on SSDs
- stripes on RAID sets
- caching blocks on powerful enterprise SAN storage systems
- etc.

This *data alignment* is good for performance reasons, and helps in minimizing the wear of SSDs. But if you want to create the partition using the same starting sector as before, add the option `-c=dos` to your `fdisk` command line:

```
fdisk -c=dos /dev/sda
```

That should allow the first sector of the partition to be less than block 2048, and you can then set it to block 63, exactly as your old partition was.

Comment: +1 for -c=dos and the 2048 vs old explanation.